# How to install joomla extension by command

Tags: php, joomla, command-line-interface, joomla3.0

I am trying to install extension by command.

In server already configure the **PHP CLI** and I'm using this code :

```
shell_exec('php-cli '.$SitefilePath.' --package='.$packagePath.'');
```

I have upload the file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akeeba/vagrant/master/vagrant/files/joomla/install-joomla-extension.php

In the **CLI** folder and pass path as `SitefilePath` into command.
but its not working.

I have checked with all option :

http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-options.shtml

Let me know how to get this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these issues have been properly debugged in the [install-joomla-extension.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akeeba/vagrant/master/vagrant/files/joomla/install-joomla-extension.php) script I wrote.

First, create a new plain text file and paste that code in it. Save it as install-joomla-extension.php in your Joomla! site's cli directory. The name is not important, the location (cli directory) is.

Now you can call it like this:

cd /path/to/site/cli php ./install-joomla-extension.php --package=/where/is/your/extension.zip

The script returns one of the following exit statuses:

1. The extension was installed successfully.
2. The package file was not found.
3. The package file could not be extracted.
4. The extension could not be installed.
   You can copy this file to your site's cli directory and install extensions and extension updates any time you want.

Source: https://www.dionysopoulos.me/238-installing-joomla-extensions-from-the-command-line.html

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for update !! :)

My problem is regarding the command PHP or PHP-CLI.

When I use PHP then it start loading and server get crashed as the server is running out of memory.

When I use PHP-CLI then it doesn’t work.

Let me know if we can pass root user access in command or there is any other solution.

Comment: Looks like the file has relocated here... https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akeeba/vagrant/master/assets/joomla/install-joomla-extension.php

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. How can I accomplish this in Joomla! 3.9? Is there a built-in solution?